# Unable to activate Windows 10 on a Dell PC

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-activation

I have a computer that I need to reinstall from scratch - disk failed.
But it is a weird one... This is 5547 laptop that came originally with Windows 8.1 Pro (says so on the invoice, shipping configuration on Dell Support website and sticker is a match). It was upgraded to windows 10 when it was available.
But installer asks for a key.

I know from experience it happens - W10 will not honor w8 DPK from BIOS, so the way is to install w8 and then upgrade to w10. But shouldn't matter for PC that ran w10 before. But seen weirder things, so fine, doing it the long way.
But that asking for PK happens for every version of the installer: W8, W8.1 and W10. This should not happen, so investigated and indeed, the key is missing in BIOS. But apparently MB was replaced by Dell at some point. They left a DPK as replacement MBs from Dell don't have DPK injected int BIOS. Fine. Using that DPK.

Reinstalling it as a W8.1 and while acceptes during install, windows activation says this DPK was blocked on the server and it can't be activated.

Warranty ended long time ago so now question is: what to do? Feeling I'm being screwed here...

**FOLLOW-UP**

I spoke with Dell Customer Care and get this:
"Sir, you'd need the Windows installation media that was sent with the computer, because you need to have genuine copy of Windows to activate. If you do not have that I cannot help you, I would need to transfer you to my colleagues to help you with installing Windows." Of course for a price that "I don't know".
When pointed out that no media is sent with the laptop and did he meant factory restore copy on the hard drive, he said yes... Too bad drive failed. And he also said there will be no DPK for windows 8.1 on this system (but I don't believe he even knew what I was talking about), because only way is the original copy on media sent with system...

Comment: "But installer asks for a key." - Have you tried to hit "Skip" at this step?  You are suppose to be able to step this step, Windows 10 will automatically detect your license key, but if the motherboard was replaced then that license no longer is applicable to   your hardware.  Contacting Microsoft with regards to the license being blocked is your best option.  **You might want to clarify what a "DPK"**

Comment: @Ramhound W10 doesn't detect W8 keys on install. it will activate on it later, but installer will not acknowledge w8 DPK (digital produck key). One can skip this step in W10, but not in W8 installer, but then again W8 installer should pick up DPK embedded in BIOS (Unless one has machine with W8, but installer is W8.1 but that's another issue). So my point is my machine doesnt have DPK embedded in BIOS at all (checked). this laptop has been upgraded to w10, but apparently after drive fail Activation Server doesn't recognize the system and says no DPK found...

Comment: "W10 doesn't detect W8 keys on install." - This isn't true.  1511 introduced the ability to install Windows 10 with Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1 license keys (OEM and Retail).

Comment: @Ramhound I'll amend my statement: In some cases it doesn't. The fact in my specific case is that I seem to not have a key at all, which should not be possible but there it is. I wonder if radical BIOS update (say after 4 years first ever) messes with windows keys, at least in Dell case...

Comment: The key isn't stored in the BIOS.  It's stored in the ACPI table, which is accessible from UEFI, but isn't actually UEFI.

Comment: @Ramhound I know, I was using my cursed mental shortcut. But thank you for pointing this out, as this actually made something clock in my brain. And reinforced my suspicion - i did a search for "BIOS update wipes activation data". Unsurprisingly i get a lot of hits for DELL machines... And it makes sense. Ok, this is now doubly on dell. In fact, I found a Dell Community thread where someone mirrors my case, just different laptop model... Because meddling with ACPI almost assuredly will change hardware hash for activation

Comment: Updated question with relevant bit of the results of the Dell Customer Care inquiry.

Comment: One doesn’t modify the ACPI table as a end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more Internet digging I do have an answer. There's no cost-effective solution, though, for computers that had installed Windows 8, and for Windows 10 there is the need to be extra careful.

So, Windows 8 option.

Apparently, some DELL computers will be shipped with pre-installed, activated Windows, but there will be no key for that Windows anywhere but in the software. If this key is not backed up then re-installation will not re-activate EXCEPT if done using DELL-supplied installation media. It can be requested when purchasing (I think it's increasingly a good idea for legacy reasons, but not strictly necessary if using W10) for the best economy, but one can also purchase it from DELL at any time. It will be more pricey the older the laptop, especially if it's out of warranty.

In my case the unofficial solution is to either buy Windows Licence or the mentioned above installation media. Not sure which option is cheaper, though.